# how to remove first N-1 lines up to a given input string

Tags: grep, sed

I'm trying to remove the first N-1 lines up to the first match of a specified string

I am very new to scripting, but from my googling I believe I have the two commands I need, but don't know how to use them together:

```
grep -n -m 1 'STRING' file.txt |sed  's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

will give me the line N

```
sed -e '1,Nd' file.txt > file2.txt
```

will remove the first N lines from file.txt and place them in file2.txt

am I able to use `'1,N-1d'?`

Further, how can I get all of the above into one line, as I am executing this from ANSYS and it doesn't carry parameters from line to line

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use `grep` and `sed` and bash arithmetic expansion, e.g.:

```
N=$(grep -n -m1 'STRING' file1.txt | cut -d: -f1)
sed "1,$(( N - 1 ))d" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

You can get the same effect with `sed`, e.g.:

```
sed '/STRING/!d; :a; n; ba' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` (both the default `mawk` and the GNU `gawk` version work for this)  to filter your file with a single command:

```bsh
awk '/STRING/{y=1} y' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Here, `/STRING/{y=1}` scans each input line for the regular expression pattern `STRING` and if it matches, set a variable `y` to 1. Both the name and value are chosen arbitrarily here, we just use this as a boolean flag to remember if we have seen the pattern you search already or not.

Then, also for each line, after performing the first check for that line, it evaluates the expression `y`. If it's a truthy value (like e.g. 1 here; while the variable being not defined yet or if it were 0 that would be falsey), `awk` performs the default action for that line, because we didn't specify any after the expression, which is to simply print that line.

That way, the variable gets set when our `STRING` pattern matches for the first time, and all lines after that, including the matched line itself get printed, those before that not.